# Chrome Extension runtime.sendmessage wait for responses

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension and Im having som problem with the `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` function

Here is how my code is set up:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage( { method : "getLocalStorage", key: "email" }, function ( response ) {
    console.log( "the response has been received" );
});

console.log( "I am here" );

$.ajax({});
```

This prints out:

```
I am here
the response has been received
```

So my problem is that chrome.runtime.sendMessage runs async with the rest of the code. So what I could do is ofcourse to put the ajax in the response function of the sendMessage. The only problem with that is that I have 3 events of sendMessage to return different variables I need before I do the ajax-call, so that is unfortunately not a viable option.

Is there any way to halt the ajax call until all the sendMessage-calls have been made?

Comment: Why not, count the responses received and, when you have the 3 responses, execute the ajax call ?

Comment: Are you trying to reinvent [`chrome.storage` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage)? Are you, here, querying the background to read `localStorage`? If you do, I can show a more efficient way.

Comment: @xan Yes, I am calling the background to retrieve information stored in the localStorage there. The user enters his/hers email as a setting which is stored in the extensions local storage. Then I retrieve this via sendMessage before I execute the ajax call. So my problem now is that if I update my email, and call for the ajax call, it gets sent to the old email address the first time, because its updated async.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider switching from the old *"store data in `localStorage`, query background with `sendMessage`"* paradigm to the new *"store data in `chrome.storage`, access anywhere"* paradigm; [`chrome.storage` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) was made specifically for this purpose.

The downside is that *all* access becomes asynchronous. But at least you can optimize a bit, for instance you can glue your calls together:

```
chrome.storage.local.get([key1, key2, key3], function(data) {
  // Use data.key1, data.key2, etc.
  $.ajax({});
});
```

You can even provide default values in case there are none yet:

```
chrome.storage.local.get({key1: default1, key2: default2, key3: default3}, function(data) {
  // Use data.key1, data.key2, etc.
  $.ajax({});
});
```

And last but not least, you've got `chrome.storage.sync` that will automatically propagate to other signed-in profiles.

Comment: Thanks xan. Good solution. I wasnt aware of the storage.local. It works perfect for my cause

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use [Async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async). Then you could do something like this:

```
async.parallel([
    function(done) {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage( { your first message }, function ( response ) {
            done();
        });
    },
    function(done) {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage( { your second message }, function ( response ) {
            done();
        });
    },
    function(done) {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage( { your third message }, function ( response ) {
            done();
        });
    }
], function() {
    console.log( "I am here" );
    $.ajax({});
})
```